# VBA initial cell change fails to fire function - subsequent changes successfully fire function - Regex Cell Validation

Tags: regex, vba, excel

The following code is supposed to prevent anyone from entering a non-numeric character.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Static X As Variant
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

If IsEmpty(X) Then X = [a1:a10].Value2

Set rng2 = Intersect([a1:a10], Target)
If rng2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rng3 In rng2
    If Not isValidRegex(rng3, "\d+") Then rng3.Value = X(rng3.Row, 1)
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

X = [a1:a10].Value2

End Sub

Function isValidRegex(rng As Range, pattern As String) As Boolean
Dim re As Object
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
re.pattern = pattern
isValidRegex = re.Test(rng.Value)
End Function
```

The problem is on the first attempt when a user changes a cell in this range A1:A10 to a non-numeric character, the isValidRegex function fails to fire... or at least I think that is the problem. Maybe it's related to the variable X.

I want the Regex pattern to be enforced at all times...

Comment: Are there any other events going on? The testing I did worked for me unless I am misunderstanding your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following code works for you

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

    Set rng2 = Intersect([a1:a10], Target)
    If rng2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each rng3 In rng2
        If Not isValidRegex(rng3, "\d+") Then Application.Undo
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This fixed the problem!